# Фон остался только у текста а у изображения пропал

Tags: html, css

```css
.blue_bg {
  background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff0000/555555?text=text');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.upp_quete {
  margin: 0em 0em 20em 0em;
}

.quete p {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0;
}

.Utug {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<section class="blue_bg">
  <div class="upp_quete">
    <div class="quete">
      <a href="#" class="Utug"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/33ff99/555555?text=text" alt="Utug"></a>
      <p>утюг Braun TS 345</p>
      <p>Утюг с пароувлажнением для непревзойденного результата</p>
      <p>cглажения даже мелких деталей одежды.</p>
      <p>Глубоко проникающий пар разглаживает самые трудные участки ткани.</p>
      <p>Безупречный результат быстро и просто.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

В `CSS` поставил текст с левой стороны, а изображение с правой.
И появилось проблема: когда я выполняю этот код на сайте синий фон остается только у текста а у изображения он пропадает и оно остается на белом фоне...
Не подскажите как это исправить?

Comment: У Вас в коде ошибка. 2 закрывающих `</div>` перед `</section>`

Comment: Если тут все работает, скорее всего у тя проблема с путями. проверь пути

Comment: о каких путях вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Путь к файлам... К картинкам...

Comment: у меня картинки и html css находятся в одном месте и путь к изображению у меня просто его название

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/unzbpvy5/

Один закрывающий `</div>` уберите просто.